# Salesforce PDF download using JSZip

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex, jszip

SFDC developer here. I have created a VF page which accepts Account id & displays some information on a VF page in tabular form.

I need to make multiple calls to this page with different account ids on a button click & download the tables in them as PDF/Text files in a zip. I was thinking about using JSZip to download all PDF/Text files as one zip.

I have got Blob value of this VF page in a variable using getContentAsPDF.

Basically i need to know how to use this Blob value for each account table and put it in separate files, download those files one Zip. Any ideas how to proceed?

EDIT 1:

So in the code below, we can see that we generating a list of Blob in the controller. On click of a VF page button i send the Blob list as a param to a JavaScript function. In that function i am trying to add each and every blob to the zip and download. But nothing is getting downloaded for me.

Apex Code:

```
CkIds = returnCommaSeparatedString(setOFCommKitID);
        pr = New PageReference('/apex/PDFPage?id=' + iICPRec +'&CKIds='+CkIds);
        pdf = pr.getContentAsPDF();
        lstOfBlob.add(pdf);
```

JavaScript Code:

```
   var IdString;
    var ArrayOfBlob = []; 
    function CallMe(TempVar, VarTemp){
        alert(TempVar);alert(VarTemp);
        IdString = TempVar;
        ArrayOfBlob = VarTemp;
        var zip = new JSZip();
        for (var i=0; i < ArrayOfBlob.length; i++)
        {
            zip.file('Test',ArrayOfBlob[0]);
        }
        var blobLink = document.getElementById('CustomLink');
        blobLink.download = "CommunicationKit.zip";
        blobLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(zip.generate());
        blobLink.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an issue with types, you should look for errors in the js console.

- in `zip.file('Test',ArrayOfBlob[0])`, [file()](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html) doesn't accept ([yet](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/224)) blobs, you need a FileReader to get the content of each file (and wait for all of them before generating the result).
- in `URL.createObjectURL(zip.generate())`, [generate()](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate.html) will give you a base64 string, you should use `generate({type:"blob"})` in your case.